# Discrepancy between calculated rectified voltage and measured value

Tags: rectifier

I'm experiencing some problems with a simple task.
Assuming we have a circuit like this:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fbx5qz.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

To calculate the rectified voltage I'd use 
$$U_{d} = \frac{1}{2 \cdot \pi} \cdot \int_{\alpha}^{\pi}{\hat{U} \cdot sin( \omega t) \cdot d \omega t}$$ 
or as mentioned [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3003799/need-verification-for-this-integral) 
$$U_{d} = \frac{1}{2 \cdot \pi} \cdot \int_{\alpha}^{\pi}{\hat{U} \cdot sin( \gamma) \cdot d \gamma}$$ 
$$U_d = \frac{\hat{U}}{2\pi} \bigg[ -cos(\gamma) \bigg]^{\pi}_{\alpha}$$ 
With $$U_\sim = 40V, \alpha = 40°$$
I measured \$23.25V\$ but using the equation I got \$11.243V\$.
I suspect the equation (or my usage of it) to be faulty. But as the equation should be correct now (according to the linked question) and the measurement should also be reasonably correct I can't say what's wrong.

Comment: This equation works for resistive loads https://www.physicsforums.com/threads/how-to-calculate-rms-voltage-from-triac-phase-angle.572668/#post-3737599

Comment: Is this 40 degree an SCR conduction angle or delay before conducting?

Comment: Sorry for leaving out that information, there was a "language barrier like" problem, i couldn't find an appropriate translation and hoped the best. However, I'd say it's the conduction angle. The literal translation from my language would be "control angle".

Comment: @G36 Sorry again I have to correct that. The voltage goes down when the angle gets bigger (at 0° I measured 24V and at 180° I measured 0.22V)!

Comment: So this equation should give you the average (DC) value, right? Also, how can you measured the 24V at 0° and 23.45V at 40 °? Something is not right. Also the solution is https://www.symbolab.com/solver/step-by-step/%5Cfrac%7B1%7D%7B2%5Cpi%7D%5Ccdot%5Cint_%7Ba%7D%5E%7B%5Cpi%7D%20V%20sin%5Cleft(w%5Cright)dw   \$V_{avr}=\frac{V_{P}}{2\pi}\cdot(1 + cos\:\alpha)\$

Comment: and the \$ \alpha\$ is delay angle before thyristor will be triggered and start to conduct the current.

Comment: Thanks @G36 So my measured values aren't reasonable? I got e.g. 23.25V for 40°, 17.1V for 90° and 7.23V for 130°. If my values aren't correct it would be the answer to my question.

Comment: For 40° the average DC voltage across the load is 0.281 times Vpeak. So what is your input voltage is?

Comment: As @G36 correctly noticed my calculations were correct. It turned out that my measured values were extremely incorrect. Can't tell what went wrong but I know that something definitely went wrong.

Comment: How did you measure the 23.25V?